# Call to undefined method DbConn::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Experimenting with PHP OO-programming and PDO and I'm getting the error:

> Call to undefined method DbConn::prepare()

My two classes are:

```
class User {
    public $conn; //db connection

    //contructor - runs code automatically when you create a User object
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new DbConn();
    }

    public function Register($username, $email, $name) {     
        //prepared statement + execute
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, email, name) VALUES (:username,:email,:name)');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'name' => $name));

        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
class DbConn {

    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "password";

    function __construct() {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oodb', $this->username, $this->password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            return $conn;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

    } //end contructor

} //end class
```

I thought that I could return the `$conn` to the User class and then call `prepare` on this but no luck.

Comment: No, running `new DbConn` will give you an object of class `DbConn`. Constructors specifically have `void` return whether you try and return something or not.

Comment: So just set up another method in the DbConn class to return the connection?

Comment: Sure. There are various options. Might be an idea to look at how various frameworks do it.

Comment: That's a nice idea - I will try that. Put your comment as an answer if you want!

Comment: Thinking about it, I wouldn't really suggest trying to extend PDO unless you know what you're doing :P.

Answer (score 2):

Leave PDO as is. It's already a class, mind you, and a pretty good one.

Make your code like this

```
class User {
    protected $conn; //db connection

    //contructor - runs code automatically when you create a User object
    function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->conn = $pdo;
    }

    public function Register($username, $email, $name) {     
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, email, name) VALUES (:username,:email,:name)');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'name' => $name));
    }
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oodb', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$user = new User($pdo);
```

It will save you A LOT of trouble.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to be able to reuse the PDO instantiation code, just place it in its own file and include it where you want it.

Answer (score -1):

You are basically returning another class object in a constructor... that is not the way to do it

Maybe what you want is a connection factory:

```
class ConnectionFactory{

    /**
     * 
     * @return \PDO
     */
    public static function getConnection(){

        $settings = self::_getSettings();

        return new PDO("{$settings['driver']}:host={$settings['host']};dbname={$settings['dbname']}", $settings['username'], $settings['password']);

    }

    private static function _getSettings(){
        //reads settings from a INI or xml...
    }

}
```